# Angular pass data to provider

Tags: angular

I am using provider to fetch data from api. i need to know how ill pass some data through component to provider.

in component

```
   constructor(    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private modalService: NgbModal, private api:ApiService, public httpClient: HttpClient, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { 

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params=> {const company_id = params['company_id'];
      console.log(company_id);
      this.company_id = company_id;
      console.log(this.company_id);
    });



if(this.company_id){

  this.api.getSamad(this.company_id);
  this.company = false;

}

else{
   this.company = true;
   this.api.getClaims();
   }


  }

  ngOnInit(){
  console.log(this.company_id);
```

}

provider

```
 constructor(    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private 
 modalService: NgbModal, public httpClient: HttpClient, private spinner: 
 NgxSpinnerService) { }

getSamad(){

console.log(this.company_id);

this.url = 'http://url.php?offset=0&limit=10&company_id='+this.company_id;

      this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).
         subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
         this.spinner.hide();

         this.data1 = data.records;
         this.data1.forEach(d => this.policy_id.add(d.policy_id));
         console.log(this.userFilter.policy_id);
```

I need to show this.company_id in provider console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In provider, Are you using this.company_id? Then it will look for the company_id local variable defined in provider class.

in component

```
    private companyId = 1001;
....
    if(this.companyId){
      this.api.getSamad(this.companyId);  
    }
```

Your provider class

```
constructor(    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private 
 modalService: NgbModal, public httpClient: HttpClient, private spinner: 
 NgxSpinnerService) { }

public getSamad(company_id: any){

console.log(company_id);
// you cannot type this.company_id as "this" refers to the provider class 
// object not the component.

this.url = 'http://url.php?offset=0&limit=10&company_id='+this.company_id;

      this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).
         subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
         this.spinner.hide();

         this.data1 = data.records;
         this.data1.forEach(d => this.policy_id.add(d.policy_id));
         console.log(this.userFilter.policy_id);
```

Suggestion Point - Please follow proper standard while you declare variable or method or creating the class. In this example - company_id --> companyId
For more information - https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: in this.company_id there is already a value.  so i need to add this     private companyId = 1001; ?

Comment: No. It's an example of how to write and pass. Of course instead of 1001, you would be getting something from your own code in this.comany_id of the component. Just don't use this again in provider class.

Comment: when im adding this     private companyId = this.company_id; like this its showing error in other functions. can you please provide example with this.company_id thanks

Comment: You don't need to add this line. Just pass your this.comapny_id from your component to this.api.getSamad() method. And then in provider class, just do how I wrote the method. Or Can you provide your complete class code of both Component and Provider?

Comment: im passing this.company_id and in provider im fetching like this                   
    public getSamad(componentthis.company_id: number){
      console.log(this.company_id); }

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.